# React library for selecting items like google drive

Tags: reactjs

Is there any library for React that can make the following:

For example I need to select multiple items by clicking to them with CTRL button pressed.
Or using SHIFT button to select all between first and last selected items.
Also it would be nice to select multiple files by dragging mouse through some area.

Thanks!